# how to use multiple ID in javascript Preloader?

Tags: javascript

that's my code

[Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hBbxA/)

```
example

$(function(){$("#album-left", "#album-right").loader();});
```

Comment: `$("#album-left, #album-right").loader();`? You’d have to actually fix your code to loop over the `$(this)` collection, though.

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have?

Comment: What `.loader()` plugin are you using? Does it handle multi-collections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CSS Selector

```
$(function(){$("#album-left, #album-right").loader();});
```